# How to compare objects belonging to different class using the IComparable interface

Tags: c#, interface, icomparable

I am trying to compare two different objects belonging to different class and sort them using `IComparable` interface. Please find my code below and where I can improve I have understood the error but don't know how to fix it.

```
public class Program : IComparable
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var newList = new List<Object>();
        newList.Add(new Program { carName = "mercedes benz", topSpeed = 160 });
        newList.Add(new SecondClass { carName = "BMW", topSpeed = 140 });
        newList.Sort();

        foreach (var list in newList)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(list.carName + " " + list.topSpeed);
             /* Getting an error on this line stating 'object' does not contain a definition for 'carName' and no extension method 'carName' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*/
        }
    }

    public string carName { get; set; }
    public int topSpeed   { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Object obj)
    {
        Program classObject = (Program)obj;

        if (this.topSpeed > classObject.topSpeed)
            return 1;
        else if (this.topSpeed == classObject.topSpeed)
             return 0;
        else return -1;
    }
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public string carName { get; set; }
    public int topSpeed   { get; set; }
}

/* Edit: implemented abstract class however I am getting this "Unhandled Exception Message": System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'CSharpbasics.SecondClass' to type 'CSharpbasics.Program'.*/

public class SecondClass : Car { }

public abstract class Car : IComparable
{
    public string carName { get; set; }
    public int topSpeed   { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Object obj)
    {
        Program classObject = (Program)obj;

        if (this.topSpeed > classObject.topSpeed)
            return 1;
        else if (this.topSpeed == classObject.topSpeed)
             return 0;
        else return -1;
    }
}

public class Program : Car
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var newList = new List<Car>();
        newList.Add(new Program { carName = "Wagon R", topSpeed = 160 });
        newList.Add(new SecondClass { carName = "Swift", topSpeed = 140 });

        newList.Sort();

        foreach (var list in newList) 
            Console.WriteLine($"{list.carName} {list.topSpeed});
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of duplicated code. You should really consider changing your design to not repreated the same code twice.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an abstract class Car which both classes inherit from, and which implements the CompareTo function. The parent class doesn't necessarily has to be abstract, but in this case I think it will be more fitting.

Comment: Did the same However i am getting this Unhandled Exception Message
 System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'CSharpbasics.SecondClass' to type 'CSharpbasics.Program'.

Comment: Can you edit the question and show the way you did it? Append it to the bottom of the question, don't delete what is already on there.

Comment: @ShravanRao you should change the casting in the CompareTo function. You're trying to cast to Program, when you should be casting to Car.

Comment: My Bad thank you alott for your help it is working fine now thanks.

Comment: No problem, just remember to mark the question as answered! :)